# backbone underscore template jquery ui glyph icon not clicking

Tags: jquery-ui, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, glyphicons

I have the following HTML code in a Backbone View Extend js as an underscore template variable:

```
var template = _template(
...
"<div class='sizingIcon'>" +
    "<ul class='ui-widget icon-collection classificationSizingIcon'>" +
        "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='minimize'>" +
            "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n resizeIcon'></span>" +
        "</li>" +
    "</ul>" +
"</div>" +
...
);
```

as well, I have this call to invoke a Backbone function in the initialize area of the view extension:

```
this.appendSizingFunctionality();
...
},

appendSizingFunctionality: function() {
    $('.resizeIcon').click(function() {
        alert('resizing div');
    });
},
....
```

I can't get a click event to trigger, even with the test code.  Yes, I have jquery, jquery-ui, backbone, and underscore loading.  Several other pages still function.  Essentially I have a few different icons I want to execute a resize function when clicked on a div.

What do you think I'm missing?

Comment: [You should not handle events like that in Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events).

Comment: @moonwave99 How should I do it then?

Comment: Like in the link I posted : ))

Comment: @moonwave99 OK, so I've got the Backbone Extension set up correctly, with an el, and an events function, still nothing triggers.  Should a trigger happen from an underscore template?

Comment: Is `.resizeIcon` inside your view's `el`? Maybe a functional example of what you're doing would help.

Comment: I'm trying the events like this:

'events : { '.resizeIcon hover' : 'function() {alert('resizing div');}' }, ...

Comment: Everything renders in my el, and other links/events work, just not the glyph hover/click

Comment: @MatthewDewell function shouldn't be a string: `events : { '.resizeIcon hover' : function() {alert('resizing div');} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your events object should look like this. The value of the key/value pair should be the name of the function that will be called when the event is triggered on the selector.

`event        selector    callback`
`'mouseover .resizeIcon':'onMouseover',`

The function is passed the `event` object. Also there is no `hover` event in js, presumably because it's actually 2 events that you need to handle separately.

```
events:{
    'mouseover .resizeIcon':'onMouseover',
    'mouseoff .resizeIcon':'onMouseoff'
},
onMouseover:function(e){

},
onMouseoff:function(e){

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That appears to work.  Now I can go about adding a click and a function for it to resize, based upon the glyph click.  I thought that with the function in the callback, it would execute that, but I guess it doesn't.  That was for testing purposes, anyway.  I guess I hade the order wrong on the selector and event.  Thank you for the clarification on that too.